# How to remove port number 8080 from my domain name using nginx v1.14.1?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I am using `node` and `express`, `AWS Ec2 Linux` and running two web apps in port number `8080` and `8081` using `pm2`.

added subdomains to my Elastic IP `admin.example.com` and `app.example.com`.

My both app running in localhost:8080 and 8081.

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf**  // After Edit

```
server {
    listen   admin.example.com:80;
    server_name  admin.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf**  // Before Edit

```
#
# A virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#

#server {
#    listen   8000;
#    listen   somename:8080;
#    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen('8080');
console.log('Server started at port 8080');
```

nginx running fine after the restart but did not remove port number 8080 from my domain.

What are the things to be done with port `80`?, I just enabled 80 from my AWS Instance inbound rule, Anything else I miss?

Comment: whats output when you access http://admin.example.com ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan - Getting `This site can’t be reached, admin.example.com took too long to respond.`

Comment: `admin.example.com` should be replacing by your domain.

Comment: Yupp, We did it !, and port number too is 8080, getting same error.

Comment: have you changed the configuration as I answsered below ?

Comment: Yes @ThanhNguyenVan

Comment: And make sure you have done create DNS record to point to your public ip address.

Comment: DNS is created and running fine with 8080 like admin.example.com:8080 @ThanhNguyenVan

Comment: Fixed the bug, Inbound rules added only `::/0` for port `80`, after remove and add `HTTP`, updated like `0.0.0.0/0, ::/0` now all runs fine. @ThanhNguyenVan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues Fixed :

Inbound rules added only `::/0` in the source for port `80`, after remove and add `HTTP`, source updated like `0.0.0.0/0, ::/0` now all runs fine.

Answer (score 5):

You are providing the domain with the port.

Try it this way:

```
server {
      server_name admin.example.com;
      listen 80;
      location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
      }
}
```

Comment: Port `80` not added to Instance Inbound rules but sub-domain points to Elastic IP. Is it need to give `80` to listen? currently, my app running in `admin.example.com:8081` without using `nginx`

Comment: We are listening on ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) and forward the request to the port on our machine (server) based on the server name. So is your project running on `http://127.0.0.1:8081;` ? If yes , whenever a request is made to the domain `admin.example.com` that is mapped to ' the Ip of your server ', your nginx configures out where to forward it (in your case it's 8081) .

Comment: Okay I agree, but how my sub domain [`admin.example.com:8081`] runs without enable HTTP(80) in the AWS?

Comment: updated my question - added `virtual.conf` file before update

Comment: Enabled port `80` from Inbound rules, and updated `virtual.conf` like you said, but did not affect anything. restared nginx after update

Comment: The problem from inbound rules added my answer for reference.

Answer (score 4):

change `virtual.conf` to :

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  admin.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

And make sure you have done creating DNS record to point to your public ip address.

Comment: DNS is created and running fine with `8080` like `admin.example.com:8080`

Comment: did you change configuration same as above and try again

Comment: Yes, I did, but no changes.

Comment: I think we might miss something from port 80 updates?, we just enabled `80` inbound rules for Instances.

Comment: open port 80 is enough for http access .

Comment: any log on nginx ?

Comment: `[emerg] 28069#0: directive "server_name" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf:8`

Comment: resolved it before only, added `;` at the end of server_name statement. now there is no bug. only this line exist in that file.

Comment: while restart the nginx getting Ok